# Can unicorns still teleport if you are riding them?

Tags: nethack

I'm thinking about taming a unicorn that resides in Sokoban (I already found a saddle). My character is a SAM w/MR + SDSM and a ring of teleport control if that matters (if it does, please alert for followup Qs)..  I know that Unis can teleport when cornered, and think this might be an interseting, if not useful, quirk to explore. I've read the wiki, but there's no mention of whether this possibly lifesaving (or possibly irritating) trait of Unis persists when ridden.  I'd like to not waste this scroll if it's a definite No.  Any facts you can share?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, no.  Unicorns don't have at-will teleportation the way normal teleporting monsters do.  Instead, they've got a special case in the monster-movement code that tries to relocate them if they're threatened by the player.  Since monsters being ridden follow the player-movement rules rather than the monster-movement rules, that means no teleporting unicorn steeds.